# Divide column values within a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I'm not sure if my title is properly expressing what I'm asking.  Once I'm done writing, it'll make sense.  Firstly, I just started learning R, so I am a newbie.  I've been reading through tutorial series and PDF's I've found online.

I'm working on a data set and I created a data frame of just the year 2001 and the DAM value Bon.  Here's a picture.

[image]

What I want to do now is create a matrix with 3 columns:  Coho Adults, Coho Jacks and the third column the ratio of Coho Jacks to Adults.  This is what I'm having trouble with.  The ratio between Coho Jacks to Adults.

If I do a line of code like this I get a normal output.

```
(cohoPassage <- matrix(fishPassage1995BON[c(5,6, 7)], ncol = 3))
```

The values are 259756, 6780 114934.

I'm figuring in order to get the ratio, I should divide column 5 and column 6's values.  So basically 259756/6780 =  38.31

I've tried many things like:

```
(cohoPassage <- matrix(fishPassage1995BON[c(5,6, 5/6)], ncol = 3))
```

This just outputs the value of the fifth column instead of dividing for some reason

I've tried this:

```
matrix(fishPassage1995BON[c(5,6)],fishPassage1995BON[,5]/fishPassage1995BON[,6], ncol = 3)
```

Which gives me an incorrect output

I decided to break down the problem and divide the fifth and sixth columns separately and it gave the correct ratio.

If I create a matrix like this

```
matrix(fishPassage1995BON[,5]/fishPassage1995BON[,6])
```

It outputs the correct ratio of 38.31209.  But when I try to combine everything, I just keep getting errors.

What can I do?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You problem is not reproducible but you can try `cbind(fishPassage1995BON[c(5,6)],fishPassage1995BON[,5]/fishPassage1995BON[,6])`

Comment: Wow, thank you.  I didn't quite understand cbind.  But I used that basic syntax and created a new vector  'blah <- matrix(cbind(fishPassage1995BON[c(5,6)],fishPassage1995BON[,5]/fishPassage1995BON[,6]))'  and this worked.